# bulk_create() and save() methods django

Tags: django-orm

I am using the bulk_create method to save multiple objects at once. But I have an overridden save() method and it is not called in this case. And I don't want to spam extra queries.

Maybe there is some kind of life hack to get the benefits of both methods?